# how to copy all source jars in the dependencies section to a directory in gradle

Tags: gradle

I can copy all the jars in dependency section for "compile" configuration like so

```
task('copyJars') { 
    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
    copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
}
```

but how do I copy their source jar files somewhere?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31451648/300053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gradle 1.0, I don't know of an easy way to deal with third-party sources Jars. You could add them as explicit dependencies (to a separate configuration) or maybe crawl the Gradle cache.

By the way, `delete ext.collection` is in the wrong spot. It will be executed in the configuration phase, and will delete files no matter which tasks are going to be executed. (Also `listFiles()` will get invoked for every build.)

Also, a task whose main purpose is copying should alway use the `Copy` task type rather than the `copy` method.

Comment: so, how should I rewrite the task better to not invoke listFile() for every build?  doesn't listFile() need to be called in case a developer added a file to that directory?  How do I rewrite it so it is only running if files added/removed into genLibDir?